# Decreasing value by given steps in non-linear way

Tags: javascript

I need to decrease a value in X steps from max to min value. The easy part would be this:

```
const data = []
const x = 6
const factor = (max - min) / x
for (let index = 1; index <= x; index++) {
    data.push(max - index * factor)
}
```

This would give me a linear result assuming there are 6 steps: `[20, 17.5, 15, 12.5, 10, 7.5, 5]` where max is `20` and min is `5`.

Unfortunately I need no linear values. First there should be fast decreasing values and at the end it should get more slowly decreasing.
Ok, for that the resolution of only 6 steps is a bad example. But the problem is the same to me: How can I calculate a more 'logarithmic' decrease? I mean something like `[20, 11, 9, 7, 6, 5]`. This is just an estimated example. I don't know how to explain it better...

Comment: Use exponential decay.